# How to send parameters from controller to view and display with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have got a really easy question about sending parameters from `Controller` to `View` with `thymeleaf`.

I have got HTML page with line:

```
<p th:text="${xyz}"></p>
```

When I acces page `http://localhost:8080/myproject-web/mypage` this `paragraph` is empty.

When I click submit button it goes to controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/subscribeth", params = { "save" })
public String save(final MyMainObject subscription, final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model) {
            System.out.println("I am here"); // it is displayed
    model.addAttribute("xyz", "Hello");
    return "redirect:/mypage";
}
```

So, it goes once again to `mypage` but the `paragraph` is still empty.

About what I forgot...? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually redirecting the page. i.e. this will ask the client to resend the request to the given page. But, what you need it just a forward / a normal view rendering of `mypage`. So, you will have to change this

```
return "redirect:/mypage";
```

to

```
return "forward:/mypage";
```

Note : You can also set the values across a redirect request using `RedirectAttributes`

Answer (score 0):

Returning "redirect:/mypage" sends makes Spring return an HTTP 302 to the user's browser for the link /mypage. Therefor when the user's browser requests that link, there is not model populated.